# Почему ymaps.geocode возвращает самый точный результат вторым?

Tags: yandex-geocoding-api, geocode

Есть скрипт, в котором я запрашиваю координаты точки по адресу.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  ymaps.ready(initYa);
  function initYa() {
    var myMap = new ymaps.Map('YaMap', {
      center: [55.751574, 37.573856],
      zoom: 9,
      controls: []
    });

    ymaps.geocode('Россия, Московская область, Пушкино, Набережная улица, 16').then(function(res) {
      
      console.log('Первый результат - '+res.geoObjects.get(0).properties.get('text'));
      console.log('Второй результат - '+res.geoObjects.get(1).properties.get('text'));
      
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU&amp;apikey=c161ad77-2e7b-4dc0-b5fc-a5bd6b1e1b86" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <style>
    #YaMap {
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
      min-height: 300px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="YaMap"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Однако первым возвращается результат с адресом: "Россия, Московская область, Пушкино, Набережная улица, 8", a требуемый результат возвращается вторым. Почему? Ведь по идее, первым должен быть результат, наиболее близкий к запросу.

results: 1 ничего не меняет. Всё работает, отдаётся один результат, но опять же Набережная 8.

Comment: Логики так и не понял. Пришлось реализовывать функционал дополнительным полем suggest, где пользователь уточняет уже введённый ранее адрес. Лишние действия, конечно, но по другому никак. Да, если отдать скрипту прям точный адрес с указанием района, то нужный адрес будет первым. На мой взгляд - странно. Какая разница, указал я район или нет. Если указан точный адрес с номером дома, не это ли должно являться основным? Так и осталось для меня загадкой. Возможно, недостаточно знаний.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не совсем понятен код, так как в карте записываете координаты, а у геокодера запрашиваете адрес. Вы полученный адрес запрашиваете у геокодера? Или вводимые пользователем - данные? Не до конца понятна реализация составляющих...

Но в любом случае, если Вы запрашивает у геокодера адрес, которые ввел пользователь - Вам необходимо предоставить выбор для пользователя - какой адрес будет являться более подходящим к запросу пользователя.

Есть механизм suggest - подойдет ли он для реализации задачи?

Например: https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/input_validation или https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/suggest, проверьте адрес, который вводит пользователь, и отправляйте его в геокодер, получите точные координаты адреса.

Повторюсь - задача не совсем понятна, надеюсь что чем то помог )

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Да, решено было в тот же день, при помощи suggest. Это не очень удобно, но пришлось уточнять адрес таким способом. Задача проста - просчёт стоимости доставки в корзине. Смысл был в том, чтобы брать адрес уже введённый пользователем ранее, при прошлых заказах, отправлять его геокодеру, вычислять расстояние и устанавливать стоимость. Но так как столкнулся с проблемой, пришлось обязать пользователя уточнять адрес.